# How to compare and validate 2 times with 2 dates in MVC C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, validation

How to compare and validate two times? 
My scenario is I need to add various schedules. Assume that `person 1 has schedules on today 18/08/2017 as Sch1: 0800-1600 and sch2:2200-0600` that is `sch1 starts and ends on same day`whereas`sch2 starts on 18/08/2017 and ends on 19/08/2017 6am.` 
Now when I try to edit Schedule end time, I want to add 2 validations that schedule end time must be greater than start time and also must be greater than current system time. How to validate these two ? When I add validation then end time after 24 hrs, it takes 19/08/2017's 1am,2am,3am as less than value of 18/08/2017's 2000,2100(8pm,9pm).

My coding for validation below

```
if ( D.ScheduleEndTime != T.EndTime && D.ScheduleEndTime < Time)
{
    return Json(new { success = "fail", message = "End Time must be greater than current time!!!" }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
else if (D.ScheduleEndTime != T.EndTime && D.ScheduleEndTime < T.StartTime)
{
   return Json(new { success = "fail", message = "End Time must be greater than start time!!!" }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

In the above code D&T. D means values that entered while editing and T means values from Table in database

Comment: Have you tried using System.DateTime type? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Your question is very unclear. What is it that you're actually having a issue with? What have you tried? What's not working? Any specific errors? What behavior is occurring? How is that behavior wrong? Think through these types of questions as you're writing your question. The better you answer them, the greater the chance someone can help you, and ironically, you'll often stumble upon the answer yourself in the process.

Comment: sry for the unclear format.. I'll update my question

Answer (score 0):

You didn't give any information on the data types you are using but sounds like you are using a custom date-time object rather than the datetime data type?

So each of your custom date-time objects have something similar to the following structure:

```
custom_datetime:
 - string Date (ie: 18/08/2017)
 - int startTime (ie: 2200)
 - int endTime (ie: 0600)
```

In that case, it would be something like this maybe...

```
// Temp variable to manipulate, instantiated to passed in custom_datetime D.
custom_datetime temp = D;
// First check if the passed in date time is different than date time stored
if ((temp.Date != T.Date) || ((temp.Date == T.Date) && (temp.endTime != T.endTime))) {
    // Then check if the endTime is less than the startTime
    // If it is, then the end time is the next day so increment the date in temp variable. Now use temp variable to do rest of the checks.
    if (temp.endTime < temp.startTime) {
        temp.Date++; // Increment to next day, so 18/08/2017 becomes 19/08/2017
    }

    //Check if passed in date < stored date, if it is, then it will also be less than startTime so return error.
    if (temp.Date < T.Date) { 
        return Json(new { success = "fail", message = "End Time must be greater than current time!!!" }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
    //Check if the passed in date is the same as the stored date. If it is, make sure the endTime is greater than the stored startTime
    else if ((temp.Date == T.Date) && (temp.endTime <= T.startTime)) {
        return Json(new { success = "fail", message = "End Time must be greater than current time!!!" }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
    //Check if the passed in date < current system date or if the passed in date == current system date but the endTime <= the current time.
    else if ((temp.Date < Time.Date) || ((temp.Date == Time.Date) && (temp.endTime <= Time.Time)) {
        return Json(new { success = "fail", message = "End Time must be greater than current time!!!" }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
}
```

The code doesn't actually work, but hopefully it gives you an idea of something you can do. Need more information to give an exact answer.